# Is it possible to define "virtual" default implemetation for getter-setter without preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, getter-setter, auto

It is possible to use template for default implemetation of getter-setter.

For instance - http://www.kirit.com/C%2B%2B%20killed%20the%20get%20%26%20set%20accessors/A%20simple%20meta-accessor. 
Most important, that if you decide to override default behaviour of such setter or getter, you can easly do this without need to change "client" code, because setter-getter calling syntax is same to calling methods, i.e.:

```
an_object.an_int( 3 );
int i = an_object.an_int();
```

In both cases an_int can be object with operator() or method of an_object. After overriding re-compilation will be required in "client" code.

But is it possible to define "virtual" default implemetation for getter-setter without preprocessor macros? i.e. important thing here is that during overide recompilation of "client" code is not needed. Of course it is possible to do with preprocessor, by I wonder, is there any more elegant solution?

For my knowladge of C++03 is not possible, but maybe someone has some ideas, or maybe it is possible in C++11?

---

Answer for "David Rodríguez - dribeas":
something like this:

```
#define accessor(type,name) \
virtual type name() {return m_##name;} \
type m_##name;
```

It can be overrided in derived class without need of recompilation of "client" code.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases you can write a real interface and don't write accessors/mutators at all. Then the problem goes away!

Comment: I cannot really understand the question, I think you might get a better idea of what you mean by "virtual" default implementation if you provided the solution you have in mind with pre processor macros (and I am really wondering how you might do something at the pre processor level and not require recompilation of the clients...)

Comment: Any object implementation you could do with the preprocessor can be done without it.

Comment: Mark B, Actually I don't have this problem now. It is just interesting to me, if it possible to do technically. I know that in many cases accessors are superfluous. BTW, I have such question after watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB-bdWKwXsU

Comment: AJG85, I need default implementation without much syntax duplication. A thought it was obvious.

Comment: I don't understand the question, either. Can you tell us, specifically, how [kirit.com](http://www.kirit.com/C%2B%2B%20killed%20the%20get%20%26%20set%20accessors/A%20simple%20meta-accessor) *isn't* the answer to your question?

Comment: Robᵩ, in kirit.com case it is impossible to "virtually" overide setter/getter in derived class

Answer (score 0):

As long as the functions aren't inline, you won't need to recompile the client code if you reimplement the functions.  You will just need to relink the client code with the new implementation.

Comment: Simmilar syntax of calling, does not mean simmilar mechanism. For instance in case of operator()  "this" passed to function will be pointer to an_int object, but in case of method an_int "this" passed to function will be pointer to an_object

Answer (score 0):

Not in a generally useful way.  It's possible that it might almost work for very specific use-cases.  The burden of maintenance to support these one offs is rarely worth the effort though.

To do this you push a lot of complexity down into this "field" type which you're writing.  This complexity will not generalize well.  It will be a huge mess that isn't any easier to use than just writing the accessors yourself.

If writing these accessors is time consuming, write free helper functions to make it easier.  These free functions are concrete and direct because they only do one thing.  Collecting behavior in this way is much more flexible and maintainable over time, even if it is perceived to be a bit more verbose.

This also has much better encapsulation.  Really, you're dumping a ton of implementation details into your interface that isn't interesting and shouldn't be there.

Comment: "To do this you push a lot of complexity down into this "field" type which you're writing", I have sense you mean solution, where "field" type will have virtual methods. But note, "field" type can't access to protected/private members/data of container class without "friend" specificator